# Snippet editor issue with its css positioning

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I have some issues with the snippet editor:

- I always play with the browser zoom and the snippet editor does not have a good behavior with that.

[image]

the popup can not even retrieve his right place

- when scrolling, outside the editor panes, it is the entire page which scrolls, and the popup follows at the place it has been defined initialy:

[image]

With that css rule, the popup stays at its place:

```
.popup{
    position:fixed !important;
    left:2% !important;
    top:2% !important;
}
```

adding it in a [userstyle](https://userstyles.org/) rule makes the job

And with a minimize button and/or a keyboard shortcut, it would be even better (for example to see the question, copy/paste code):

[image]

Comment: I added this UserStyles: https://userstyles.org/styles/114209/stack-snippet-editor-scrolling-fix